# Организация базы данных для хранения медиа файлов

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Основной вопрос, как организовать хранение:

- фотографий разных размеров
- видео разных размеров на нескольких языках
- аудио на нескольких языках

Например, есть объект `Человек`, нужно хранить, что этот человек может выглядеть по разному на фотографиях, умеет говорить на нескольких языках и показать как он умеет говорить на нескольких языках (нет жёсткой корреляции с языками аудио).

При этом фотографии `Животных` могут быть других размеров, т.е. настройки размеров фотографий для разных объектов будут разные. И настройки аудио и видео тоже, например, длина аудио/видео для Человека должна быть длиннее, чем длина аудио/видео для Животного.

Как проще всего организовать хранение всего этого в базе данных? И как это организовать в коде? Язык может быть любой (у меня это PHP), больше интересует сама идея.

Comment: хранить бинарную информацию лучше, конечно, в файлах, а не в базе данных. а в базе данных сохранять [uri —унифицированный идентификатор ресурса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI).

Comment: с этим то понятно, файлы будут отдельно от бд, в бд будут только ссылки на файлы, это даже не обсуждается. вопрос касается именно организация базы

Comment: неясно, что за задачу вы решаете. например: *длина аудио/видео для Человека должна быть длиннее, чем длина аудио/видео для Животного* — какое отношение это может иметь к базе данных и/или к «коду»?

Comment: это к тому, что конфигурация для медиа файлов разная для разных объектов. т.е. для Человека нужны фотографии не меньше 100x300px , а для Животного не меньше 50х50px. Это нужно как-то хранить в коде, некий конфиг для объектов

Answer (score 4):

Один из возможных вариантов хранения медиа-файлов может быть следующий, организуем таблицу media где храним все файлы (фото, видео, аудио и т.п.) с самой общей информацией о файле.

```
Таблица media
id - первичный ключ
media_file_id - внешний ключ в таблице 
media_class - имя класса в приложении (users, animals, audios, videos)
filename - названия файла, путь формируется автоматически и не хранится в таблицу
mime_type - MIME-тип файла
size - размер файла
```

В таблице имеется составной внешний ключ (`media_file_id`, `media_class`), который ссылается на другую таблицу, которая уже задает класс для файла. Например, пользователей можно хранить в таблице `users`

```
Таблица users
id - первичный ключ
first_name - имя
last_name - фамилия
email - электронный адрес
nickname - никнейм
```

Ссылка на автарку в таблице `media` будет содержать первичный ключ `user.id` в поле `media.media_file_id` и строку 'users' в поле `media.media_class`. Стили вроде 50x50 можно вообще нигде не хранить, а подразумевать по умолчанию.

Для таблицы животных, можно завести отдельную таблицу, каждая запись в которой соответствует одной фотографии животного (имена файлов по прежнему хранятся в `media`)

```
Таблица amimals_photos
id - первичный ключ
title - заголовок
author - автор фото
animal_id - внешний ключ для таблицы животных animal
```

В таблице `media` будет содержать первичный ключ `amimals_photos.id` в поле `media.media_file_id` и строку 'amimals' в поле `media.media_class`.

Если имеются какие-то видео материалы, можно завести отдельную таблицу с параметрами для видео

```
Таблица videos
id - первичный ключ
description - описание
duration - длительность видео
```

В таблице `media` будет содержать первичный ключ `videos.id` в поле `media.media_file_id` и строку 'videos' в поле `media.media_class`.

Если имеются какие-то аудио материалы, можно завести отдельную таблицу с параметрами для аудио-файлов

```
Таблица audios
id - первичный ключ
description - описание
duration - длительность аудио
```

В таблице `media` будет содержать первичный ключ `audios.id` в поле `media.media_file_id` и строку 'audios' в поле `media.media_class`.